# How to make a function run at custom fps in Godot using Gdscript

Tags: godot, gdscript

I want to make a timer function in Godot that would use the computers frame rate in order to run code at whatever fps I choose (ex. 60 fps). So far I have code for a basic timer:

```
var t = Timer.new()
t.set_wait_time(time)
t.set_one_shot(true)
self.add_child(t)
t.start()
yield(t, "timeout")
t.queue_free()
```

However rather than having the time variable be a set number, I would like it to change based on how fast the computer can run, or time between frames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to make a timer function in Godot that would use the computers frame rate

That would be code in `_process`. If you have VSync enabled in project settings (Under Display -> Window -> Vsync, it is enabled by default), `_process` will run once per frame.

> run code at whatever fps I choose (ex. 60 fps)

Then that is not the computer frame rate, but the one you say. For that you can use `_physics_process`, and configure the rate in project settings (Under Physics -> Common -> Physics Fps, it is 60 by default).

---

If what you want is to have something run X times each frame, then I'm going to suggest just calling it X times either in `_process` or `_physics_process` depending on your needs.

> I would like it to change based on (...) time between frames.

You could also use `delta` to know the time between frame and decide based on that how many times to run your code.

---

If you want to use a `Timer`, you can set the `process_mode` to `Physics` to tie it to the physics frame rate. `Idle` will use the graphics frame rate.

---

From your code it appear you don't want to connect to the `"timeout"` signal, but `yield` instead. In that case, you might be interested in:

```
yield(get_tree(), "idle_frame")
```

Which will resume execution the next graphics frame.

Or…

```
yield(get_tree(), "physics_frame")
```

Which will resume execution the next physics frame.

*Heck, by doing that, you can put all your logic on `_ready` and don't use `_process` or `_physics_process` at all. I don't recommend it, of course.*

---

If you want a faster rate than the graphics and physics frames, then I suggest you check `OS.get_ticks_msec` or `OS.get_ticks_usec` to decide when to use `yield`.

---

Assuming you want to avoid both physics and graphics frames entirely, you can instead create a `Thread` and have it sleep with `OS.delay_msec` or `OS.delay_usec`. For abstract, you would do an infinite loop, call a delay each iteration, and then do whatever you want to do.

*I made an stopwatch class for [an answer on Gamedev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/192198/10408) that you may use or base your code on. It has a `"tick"` signal, and measure running time, with support for pausing, resuming, stopping and starting again. It is NOT optimized for short intervals. Its design goal was to archive a lower rate with lower CPU usage than just checking the time each frame.*

---

> I would like it to change based on how fast the computer can run

If you se a `Thread` with an infinite loop, and no delays… Well, it will run as fast as it can run.